# Android: How is java supported in android?

Tags: android

The problem is regarding the android architecture. The apps are written in java so how is java supported in android? How are the set of C/C++ libraries used by the android apps, if they are written in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI

Comment: This question does not belong here. Google for some time and you should be able to understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please research your topic before submitting a question. 
If you want to understand how Android handles Java etc. you need to be read up on internals of Android. I will suggest just search for Android Internals.

Try this video as well: [Marakana Android Internals](http://marakana.com/s/andevcon_android_internals,271/index.html)
Marko explains the internals of Android very nicely for the beginners. There are lots of other resources on Marakana as well such as beginning Android development and building custom roms. If you are new to Android I stronly recommend going through all the Marakana videos. Goodluck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to android development and I hope to learn the concepts while learning to develop apps. The site you mentioned seems like a good one. I'll go through the videos.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/352920/1351347

This explains how C/C++ libs are translated/used in Android.

The lowlevel API is writen in C/C++, but about this you shouldnt care. Furthermore the whole Android APIs are written in java and are openSource, so you can have a look on it.

Comment: thanks! I'll go through it and search more.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You should have a look at architecture of android before posting such questions. I'm not certain about what kind of `how` you are looking for. But the question as to `How are the set of C/C++ libraries used by the android apps, if they are written in java?` -- then you should know that it is the magic of android application framework.

You might want to have a thorough read of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html).

Comment: thanks! I'm following the android developer tutorials and that's where this question occurred to me. I'll search more.